# SyncFusion Blazor Server

Tags: blazor

Me gustaría poner los bordes redondeados del contenedor blanco del SfCircularGauge, no me refiero al componente en si, lo quiero redondear es el contorno blanco el rectangulo blanco donde esta alojado el componente, no se si se pueda
[image: Las esquinas rojas las quiero redondear no se si es como en css Border-Radius 20px 20px 20px 20px]